# MediaRecorder.prepare() throwing IOException

Tags: java, android, ioexception, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I have an IOException caused by MediaRecorder.prepare(), and I have found no solution for it, even after searching in multiple places. I have used the code in the official Android Developers guide for this. My code is the following:

```
private void startRecording(String fileName) {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("RecordApp", "prepare() failed " + fileName);
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}
```

I know for a fact that the filename string is not null, as it is controlled by an EditText which I know is working properly for sure.

Just to clarify what the string filename is. Since I plan to have this data on internal storage, I just have the plain name (say I want the file to be "test"), which in this case would be the string "test". I don't know if that would be an issue or not, however.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT 1: A new issue arising (look at the first comment at @Burrough 's post).

```
private void stopRecording(){
        if(recorder != null){
            recorder.stop();
        }
    }

// stopRecording name of the button.
stopRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                thread.interrupt();
                onorig=false;
                thread = null;
                startRecording.setEnabled(true);
                stopRecording.setEnabled(false);
                try {
                    Log.i("DOG", processCode(originalcode));
                    Log.i("DOG", processCode(code));
                    Log.i("DOG", Arrays.toString(checkNotes(originalcode, code)));
                } catch(NullPointerException npe){}
                code = "";
                stopRecording();
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            }
        });
```

I am using TarsosDSP pitch recognition.

Comment: did you put the right permissions?

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filename is causing the error. Replace this:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
```

With something like this:

```
final File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), fileName);

mRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I am now getting an IllegalStateException, preceding a notification stating that stop() was called in an invalid state: 4. I do not know why this would be happening. Additional code has been added in the original question. Thank you so much! @Burrough

Answer (score 0):

Following @Proxytype, if targetsdk is api 23 or above then audio recording is seen as dangerous and you need to ask for permission every time, not just at install through the manifest. [See docs here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have declared permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Of course, if you are running on android 6.0 and above - you have to ask them in runtime, as any other dangerous permissions, if you need more information about asking permissions in runtime check the link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

And make sure your file exist, if it's absent you get this error too instead of file not found.

Comment: Like I said, I was planning to save the data in internal storage. Is the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE parameter required in this case? Should I be using external storage?

Comment: Then we have two possibilities: 
a) file actually is not in internal storage right now
b) MediaRecorder use external storage access under the wheels

Comment: I have tried this method, it still is not working. @A.Shevchuk